# Deleting Converted Leads from Marketing Clouds

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, lead-conversion, contact-deletion

My Marketing Cloud account has 3 synchronised data extensions: Lead, Contact and Account.

We recently went over out contact limit, and I discovered that Marketing Cloud syncs converted leads twice, once to the lead DE and once to the contact DE.

I read in other articles that this causes a duplication in contact count.

Consequently I identified the converted leads using the following query:

```
select _contactkey as contactkey, convertedcontactid, email, id
from
lead_salesforce
where
convertedcontactid is not null
```

I placed it in a DE that made sure to have ID as the subscriberkey. I then changed my lead synchronised DE settings to only sync records with isconverted = false and then successfully ran a contact delete on the DE I created.

However my contact count did not go down, I ran the contact count report a week later and it had not reduced

My synchronised leads DE now has only approx 4000 records, but the contact count report still shows me as having approx 6000 leads.

Additionally the contact count report does not add up to me as the total leads + total contacts does not equal the total distinct contact count:

[image: contact count report]

Please could anyone advise:

- Should deleting converted leads (but leaving their resulting contact) in SFMC reduce overall contact count?
- If so do you know why it hasn't worked for me?
- Could anyone explain the numbers to me in the contact count report and why they don't add up?

Comment: Have you actually deleted them from SFMC or just stopped synching them?

Comment: Have you performed the contact deletion to the DE you queried above? If you did, is it already finished or not? You can go to Contact Analytics tab in Contact Builder to check

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj and duc le. Yes I stopped them syncing and ran the contact delete. The contact delete processed successfully and completed over a week ago. I then ran the contact count report the following saturday (when it refreshes) and the number had not decreased

Comment: @PeterIrving I would recommend you 1.) Go to Contact Builder >> **Data Sources** >> Synchronized>>Synchronized Lead source >> on the top right corner, click on refresh arrow icon to check if it still has 4k records or 6k records  2.) If you still have a backup of the DE, go to Contact builder >> All contacts >> put a Lead ID from the backup DE and search to see whether it is still existing in the All contacts list or not

Comment: @DucLe Thanks. I checked in the synced de it only 4K records. I don't have a backup but I was under the impression that once a lead had converted you couldnt find it in all contacts by searching on the old Lead ID only on the new contact id?